# Why does this approximate a Lamé curve so well?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I was playing around with Desmos (superellipse / Lamé curve) and found, in the real number range of $0 \le x \le 1$, $0 \le y \le 1$ , two curves that are very close together:

$$x^z + y^z = 1 \tag{S}$$
$$(1-x)^{w} + (1 - y)^{w} = 1 \tag{T}$$

Whenever $2^{-1/z} + 2^{-1/w}=1$.  This last equation can be found by setting $x=y$ in the first two equations and eliminating $x$ between them.  Here it is on Desmos with a slider: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lhhyxn7bby

That both graphs share $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $y=x$ is fairly easy to see, they were made for that purpose.  And maybe the reason the graphs are so close is that they share those 3 points and are both symmetric in $x$ and $y$.

Instead of a plot though, is there a simple algebraic (e.g. symbolic, or analytical) way to show that these families of curves are so close together?